# Postgres: How to log down the locks for a transaction that is created by Spring JPA

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an operation made from Java Spring application, it produces a log like below with the number before LOG: is the transaction ID (%x) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-logging.html

```
2021-11-08 06:55:26.834 UTC [134] 0 LOG:  execute S_4: BEGIN
2021-11-08 06:55:26.836 UTC [134] 0 LOG:  execute <unnamed>: /* insert ENTITY1 */ 
    RETURNING *
2021-11-08 06:55:26.881 UTC [134] 19573 LOG:  execute <unnamed>: /* insert ENTITY2 */ 
    RETURNING *
2021-11-08 06:55:28.165 UTC [134] 19573 LOG:  execute <unnamed>: /* update ENTITY1 */
--Some more things--
2021-11-08 06:55:30.357 UTC [155] 0 LOG:  execute <unnamed>: BEGIN
2021-11-08 06:55:30.357 UTC [155] 0 LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    RETURNING *
2021-11-08 06:55:30.400 UTC [155] 19576 LOG:  execute S_1: COMMIT
2021-11-08 06:55:30.452 UTC [134] 19573 LOG:  execute <unnamed>: /* update ENTITY1 */ update ...
2021-11-08 06:55:32.395 UTC [155] 0 LOG:  execute <unnamed>: BEGIN READ ONLY
2021-11-08 06:55:32.396 UTC [155] 0 LOG:  execute <unnamed>: select ...
2021-11-08 06:55:32.438 UTC [155] 0 LOG:  execute S_1: COMMIT
2021-11-08 06:55:32.564 UTC [155] 0 LOG:  execute S_2: BEGIN READ ONLY
2021-11-08 06:55:32.565 UTC [155] 0 LOG:  execute S_3: select ...
2021-11-08 06:55:32.606 UTC [155] 0 LOG:  execute S_1: COMMIT
2021-11-08 06:55:32.648 UTC [155] 0 LOG:  execute <unnamed>: select 
2021-11-08 06:55:32.864 UTC [134] 19573 LOG:  execute S_1: COMMIT
```

I see that for some reason the transaction is running for really long (a few seconds)

My question:

- Given that I only do insert single entity and update always with a WHERE, can this cause table level lock?
- Is there a way I can log out either from Postgres side or Java side when and which type of locks is acquired by this operation - and for how long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given that I only do insert single entity and update always with a
> WHERE, can this cause table level lock?

Queries or Updates with a where cause can take time if there is no index on the column used in where column. You can try [explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-explain.html) to figure out as well.

> Is there a way I can log out either from Postgres side or Java side
> when and which type of locks is acquired by this operation - and for
> how long?

Since your code does not look like explicitly taking any database locks - the locks will be taken implicitly during SQL execution by the database engine. Postgres provides different views to query the lock level information. You can refer to [this](https://www.highgo.ca/2020/02/21/have-an-eye-on-locks-of-postgresql/) and official [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/view-pg-locks.html) for different queries to get lock information from Postgres side.